# FTP copy a file to another place in same FTP

Tags: ftp

I need to upload same file to 2 different place in same FTP. Is there a way to copy the file on the FTP to the other place instead of upload it again? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to copy files without downloading and re-uploading, at least I found nothing like this in the [List of FTP commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands) and no client I have seen so far supported something like this.

Answer (score 22):

There's no standard way to duplicate a remote file over the FTP protocol. Some FTP servers support proprietary or non-standard extensions for this though.

---

Some FTP clients do support the remote file duplication. Either using the extensions or via a temporary local copy of the remote file.

For example [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/) does [support the duplication](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_move_duplicate) using both drag&drop and menu/keyboard command:

- It supports the `SITE CPFR`/`CPTO` FTP extension (supported for example by the [ProFTPD `mod_copy` module](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_copy.html))
- It falls back to an automatic duplication via a local temporary copy, if the above extension is not available.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

Another workaround is to open a second connection to the FTP server and make the server upload the file to itself by piping a passive mode data connection to an active mode data connection. This solution is shown in the [answer by @SaadAchemlal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3808799/850848#46785089). This is basically use of [FXP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol), but for one server. Though many FTP servers will reject this, as they wont allow data connection to/from an address different to the client's.

---

Side note: people often confuse *move* with *copy*. In case you actually want to *move*, then that's a completely different question. Moving file on FTP is widely supported.

Comment: I would like to thank you for the awesome tool that is WinSCP.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the FTP protocol itself can support this in theory. The [FTP RFC 959](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959) discusses this in section 5.2 (see the paragraph starting with "When data is to be transferred between two servers, A and B..."). However, I don't know of any client that offers this sort of dual server control operation.

Note that this method could transfer the file from the FTP server to itself using its own network, which won't be as fast as a local file copy but would almost certainly be faster than downloading and then reuploading the file.

Comment: I wonder if you used this and specified localhost if you could get around that minor bottleneck. Even so, we need to consider that many FTP servers block FXP (also known as server-to-server transfers) due to "FTP bounce attacks". But a smart FTP server won't block it for localhost. Still, it might just block all FXP.

Answer (score 1):

I can copy files between remote folders in Linux based systems.
In my particular case, I'm using very common file manager PCManFM:

- Menu "Go" --> "Connect to server"
- FTP Login info, etc
- Open new tab in PCManFM
- Connect to same server
- Copy from tab to tab...

It's a bit slow, so I guess that it could be downloading and uploading back the files, but it's done automatically and very user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

The code below makes the FTP server to upload the file to itself (using loopback connection). It needs the FTP server to allow both passive and active connection mode.

If you want to understand the ftp commands here is a list of them : [List of ftp commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands)

```php
function copyFile($filePath, $newFilePath)
{
    $ftp1 = ftp_connect('192.168.1.1');
    $ftp2 = ftp_connect('192.168.1.1');
    ftp_raw($ftp1, "USER ftpUsername");
    ftp_raw($ftp1, "PASS mypassword");
    ftp_raw($ftp2, "USER ftpUsername");
    ftp_raw($ftp2, "PASS mypassword");

    $res = ftp_raw($ftp2, "PASV");
    $addressAndPort = substr($res[0], strpos($res[0], '(') + 1);
    $addressAndPort = substr($addressAndPort, 0, strpos($addressAndPort, ')'));

    ftp_raw($ftp1, "CWD ." . dirname($newFilePath));
    ftp_raw($ftp2, "CWD ." . dirname($filePath));
    ftp_raw($ftp1, "PORT ".$addressAndPort);

    ftp_raw($ftp1, "STOR " . basename($newFilePath));
    ftp_raw($ftp2, "RETR " . basename($filePath));

    ftp_raw($ftp1, "QUIT");
    ftp_raw($ftp2, "QUIT");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by using WebDrive to mount the ftp as a local folder, then "download" the files using filezilla directly to the folder. It was a bit slower than download normally is, but you dont need to have the space on your hdd.

Comment: I think it will still download the file temporarily to your machine and then immediately upload it to your webdrive.  I suspect you will still require adequate diskspace to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another workaround using PHP cUrl to execute a copy request on the server by feeding parameters from the local machine and reporting the outcome:

Local code:
In this simple test routine, I want to copy the leaning tower photo to the correct folder, Pisa:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array ('pic' => 'leaningtower', 'folder' => 'Pisa');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://travelphotos.com/copypic.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Server code (copypic.php):
On the remote server, I have simple error checking.  On this server I had to mess with the path designation, i.e., I had to use "./" for an acceptable path reference, so you may have to tinker with it a bit.

```
$pic = $_POST["pic"];
$folder = $_POST["folder"];
if (!$pic || !$folder) exit();

$sourcePath = "./unsortedpics/".$pic.".jpg";
$destPath =   "./sortedpics/".$folder."/".$pic.".jpg";

if (!file_exists($sourcePath )) exit("Source file not found");
if (!is_dir("./sortedpics/".$folder)) exit("Invalid destination folder");
if (!copy($sourcePath , $destPath)) exit("Copy not successful");
echo "File copied";
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this from C-Panel.

1. Log into your C-Panel.
2. Go into file manager.
3. Find the file or folder you want to duplicate.
4. Right-click and chose Copy.
5. Type in the new director you want to copy to.

Done!

Comment: 1) don't leave a 'signature' in your post, that's where your profile is for 2) C-Panel is only available in very specific cases.

Answer (score -3):

You can rename the file to be copied into the full path of your wanted result.

For example:
If you want to move the file "file.txt" into the folder "NewFolder" you can write it as

```
ftp> rename file.txt NewFolder/file.txt
```

This worked for me.

Comment: This misses the point of the question - OP explicitly asked about *copying*, not about *moving*