# How to copy a file on the FTP server to a directory on the same server in Java?

Tags: java, ftp, client-server, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I'm using Apache Commons FTP to upload a file. Before uploading I want to check if the file already exists on the server and make a backup from it to a backup directory on the same server.

**Does anyone know how to copy a file from a FTP server to a backup directory on the same server?**

```
public static void uploadWithCommonsFTP(File fileToBeUpload){
    FTPClient f = new FTPClient();
    FTPFile backupDirectory;
    try {
        f.connect(server.getServer());
        f.login(server.getUsername(), server.getPassword());
        FTPFile[] directories = f.listDirectories();
        FTPFile[] files = f.listFiles();
        for(FTPFile file:directories){
            if (!file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("backup")) {
                backupDirectory=file;
            } else {
               f.makeDirectory("backup");
            }
        }
        for(FTPFile file: files){
            if(file.getName().equals(fileToBeUpload.getName())){
                //copy file to backupDirectory
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

---

**Edited code:** still there is a problem,  when i backup zip file, the backup-ed file is corrupted.

**Does any body know the reason for it?**

```
 public static void backupUploadWithCommonsFTP(File fileToBeUpload) {
    FTPClient f = new FTPClient();
    boolean backupDirectoryExist = false;
    boolean fileToBeUploadExist = false;
    FTPFile backupDirectory = null;
    try {
        f.connect(server.getServer());
        f.login(server.getUsername(), server.getPassword());
        FTPFile[] directories = f.listDirectories();
        // Check for existence of backup directory
        for (FTPFile file : directories) {
            String filename = file.getName();
            if (file.isDirectory() && filename.equalsIgnoreCase("backup")) {
                backupDirectory = file;
                backupDirectoryExist = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!backupDirectoryExist) {
            f.makeDirectory("backup");
        }
        // Check if file already exist on the server
        f.changeWorkingDirectory("files");
        FTPFile[] files = f.listFiles();
        f.changeWorkingDirectory("backup");
        String filePathToBeBackup="/home/user/backup/";
        String prefix;
        String suffix;
        String fileNameToBeBackup;
        FTPFile fileReadyForBackup = null;
        f.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        f.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            if (file.isFile() && file.getName().equals(fileToBeUpload.getName())) {
                prefix = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file.getName());
                suffix = ".".concat(FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getName()));
                fileNameToBeBackup = prefix.concat(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString().concat(suffix));
                filePathToBeBackup = filePathToBeBackup.concat(fileNameToBeBackup);
                fileReadyForBackup = file;
                fileToBeUploadExist = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // If file already exist on the server create a backup from it otherwise just upload the file.
        if(fileToBeUploadExist){
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            f.retrieveFile(fileReadyForBackup.getName(), outputStream);
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
            if(f.storeUniqueFile(filePathToBeBackup, is)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup succeeded.");
                f.changeWorkingDirectory("files");
                boolean reply = f.storeFile(fileToBeUpload.getName(), new FileInputStream(fileToBeUpload));
                if(reply){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Upload succeeded.");
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Upload failed after backup.");
                }
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Backup failed.");
            }
        }else{
            f.changeWorkingDirectory("files");
            f.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            f.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToBeUpload);
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(fileToBeUpload));
            boolean reply = f.storeFile(fileToBeUpload.getName(), in);
            System.out.println("Reply code for storing file to server: " + reply);
            if(!f.completePendingCommand()) {
                f.logout();
                f.disconnect();
                System.err.println("File transfer failed.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            if(reply){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File uploaded successfully without making backup." +
                        "\nReason: There wasn't any previous version of this file.");
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Upload failed.");
            }
        }
        //Logout and disconnect from server
        in.close();
        f.logout();
        f.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using apache commons net `FTPClient`, there is a direct method to move a file from one location to another location (if the `user` has proper permissions).

```
ftpClient.rename(from, to);
```

or, If you are familiar with `ftp commands`, you can use something like

```
ftpClient.sendCommand(FTPCommand.yourCommand, args);
if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpClient.getReplyCode())) {
     //command successful;
} else {
     //check for reply code, and take appropriate action.
}
```

If you are using any other client, go through the documentation, There wont be much changes between client implementations.

**UPDATE:**

Above approach moves the file to `to` directory, i.e, the file won't be there in `from` directory anymore. Basically ftp protocol meant to be transfer the files from `local <-> remote` or `remote <-> other remote` but not to transfer with in the server.

The work around here, would be simpler, get the complete file to a local `InputStream` and write it back to the server as a new file in the back up directory.

to get the complete file,

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ftpClient.retrieveFile(fileName, outputStream);
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
```

now, store this stream to backup directory. First we need to change working directory to backup directory.

```
// assuming backup directory is with in current working directory
ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);//binary files
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("backup");
//this overwrites the existing file
ftpClient.storeFile(fileName, is);
//if you don't want to overwrite it use storeUniqueFile
```

Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

I am using apache's library .

**ftpClient.rename(from, to)**  will make it easier, i have mentioned in the code below
where to add ftpClient.rename(from,to).

```
public void goforIt(){


        FTPClient con = null;

        try
        {
            con = new FTPClient();
            con.connect("www.ujudgeit.net");

            if (con.login("ujud3", "Stevejobs27!!!!"))
            {
                con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
                con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                String data = "/sdcard/prerakm4a.m4a";
                ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data));
                boolean result = con.storeFile("/Ads/prerakm4a.m4a", in);
                in.close();
                if (result) 
                       {
                            Log.v("upload result", "succeeded");
```

//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$Add the backup Here$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$//

```
                   // Now here you can store the file into a backup location

                  // Use ftpClient.rename(from, to) to place it in backup
```

//$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$Add the backup Here$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$//

```
                       }
                con.logout();
                con.disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

    }
```

Comment: I should checkout if file exist in server then make backup then upload the file. i think you did here something else

Comment: Look at it properly once again, if (result) is the block which will execute after the file is successfully stored on the server.....

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard way to duplicate a remote file over FTP protocol. Some FTP servers support proprietary or non-standard extensions for this though.

---

So if your are lucky that your server is ProFTPD with [`mod_copy` module](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_copy.html), you can use [`FTP.sendCommand`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#sendCommand(java.lang.String)) to issue these two commands:

```
f.sendCommand("CPFR sourcepath");
f.sendCommand("CPTO targetpath");
```

---

The second possibility is that your server allows you to execute arbitrary shell commands. This is even less common. If your server supports this you can use `SITE EXEC` command:

```
SITE EXEC cp -p sourcepath targetpath
```

---

Another workaround is to open a second connection to the FTP server and make the server upload the file to itself by piping a passive mode data connection to an active mode data connection. Implementation of this solution (in PHP though) is shown in [FTP copy a file to another place in same FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3808799/850848#46785089).

---

If neither of this works, all you can do is to download the file to a local temporary location and re-upload it back to the target location. This is that the [answer by @RP- shows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11202215/850848#11202590).

---

See also [FTP copy a file to another place in same FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3808799/850848).

Answer (score -1):

To backup at same Server (move), can you use:

```
String source="/home/user/some";
String goal  ="/home/user/someOther";
FTPFile[] filesFTP = cliente.listFiles(source);

clientFTP.changeWorkingDirectory(goal);  // IMPORTANT change to final directory

for (FTPFile f : archivosFTP) 
   {
    if(f.isFile())
       {
        cliente.rename(source+"/"+f.getName(), f.getName());
       }
   }
```

Comment: This does not backup/copy a file, it moves a file. That's not what this question is about.