# Duplicate remote file over FTP protocol in Java (cp -p to Linux using sendCommand)

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I m using Apache `FTPClient`. I was a do a copy of file in a folder just like `cp -p`, but from Java. How can I do that using 'sendCommand' method or will it be possible any other way? The `rename` method moves the file but does not keep a backup copy.

Answer (score 2):

There's no standard way to duplicate a remote file over FTP protocol. Some FTP servers support proprietary or non-standard extensions for this though.

---

So if your are lucky that your server is ProFTPD with [`mod_copy` module](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_copy.html), you can use `FTP.sendCommand` to issue these two commands:

```
CPFR sourcepath
CPTO targetpath
```

---

The second possibility is that your server allows you to execute arbitrary shell commands. This is not common either. If your server supports this you can use `SITE EXEC` command:

```
SITE EXEC cp -p sourcepath targetpath
```

---

Another workaround is to open a second connection to the FTP server and make the server upload the file to itself by piping a passive mode data connection to an active mode data connection. Implementation of this solution in PHP is shown in [FTP copy a file to another place in same FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3808799/850848#46785089).

---

If neither of this works, all you can do is to download the file to a local temporary location and re-upload it back to the target location.

See also:

- [FTP copy a file to another place in same FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3808799/850848).
- [How to copy a file on the FTP server to a directory on the same server in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11202215/850848)