# How to copy a file in FTP server using FTPClient in Java?

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons-net

I have a CSV file, and I need to copy it and rename it *in the same path*.

I tried this after the FTP login:

```
InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(cvs_name +".csv");
ftpClient.storeFile(cvs_name2 + ".csv",inputStream);
```

But when I verify the file on the server, it's empty. How can I copy a file and rename it?

Comment: This question has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202215/how-to-copy-a-file-on-the-ftp-server-to-a-directory-on-the-same-server-in-java)

Comment: I already saw it, but in that case it's in different directory, I think if I use it in the same directory it will overwrite the original file, and that's not what I need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your code cannot work. You cannot download and upload a file over a single FTP connection at the same time.

You have two options:

- Download the file completely first (to a temporary file or to a memory).

  The accepted answer to [How to copy a file on the ftp server to a directory on the same server in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11202215/850848) shows the "to memory" solution. Note the `outputStream.toByteArray()` call.
- Open two connections (two instances of the `FTPClient`) and copy the file between the instances.

  ```
  InputStream inputStream = ftpClient1.retrieveFileStream(cvs_name + ".csv");
  ftpClient2.storeFile(cvs_name2 + ".csv", inputStream);
  ```