# Copy files from one FTP server to another FTP server in Java

Tags: java, ftp, sftp

I want to copy a file from one FTP server to another FTP server (two different hosts).

```
Files.copy(
    new File(channelSftp.realpath(fileName)).toPath(),
    new File(channelSftp2.realpath(fileName)).toPath());
```

It is giving `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Seeing your question history: You really should do some research, before asking!

Comment: I don't want to copy from one folder to another, I want to copy a file from one FTP address to another FTP address(I mean 2 different hosts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, thanks for the help.

it is working with following code:

sftp2.put(sftp.get(fileName),fileName);

Comment: sftp and sftp2 are two different FTP servers

Answer (score 1):

### FTP

In general, you cannot directly transfer a file from one remote FTP server to another remote FTP server, if FTP protocol is the only way you can access the machines.

There's [FXP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol) that allows that, but that's typically not allowed on most FTP servers, as they are usually configured not to accept data connections from IP addresses that are different to client IP address.

---

The only reliable solution is to download the file to local machine and upload it to the other FTP server.

You can basically use the same solutions as are shown in these answers for coping file from one directory to another on the same FTP server:

- [How to copy a file in FTP server using FTPClient in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37663865/850848)
- [How to copy a file on the ftp server to a directory on the same server in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11202215/850848)

(but for both you obviously need two instances of `FTPClient`)

---

If you have another access to one of the servers, like SSH, you can of course automatically login to the server and then run FTP on it to upload/download to/from the other server.

---

### SFTP

Though despite your wording, your question seems to actually be about SFTP, not FTP. Those are two completely different protocols.

SFTP does not support transfer between servers at all. See

- [How can I copy/duplicate a file to another directory using SFTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28089821/850848)

So again, you will typically end up downloading the file to a local machine and uploading to the other server.

Again, use the same code as shown there for coping file from one SFTP directory to another, just use two different hosts:

- [How do I transfer a file from one directory to another using Java SFTP Library JSch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32787456/850848)

Or if you have a shell access to one of the server, you can programmaticaly execute some SFTP client to upload/download a file to/from the other server. But that's a completely different question.