# Copy file from ftp server to another folder in the same server

Tags: java, javafx, ftp

i have ftp server and on him i have 2 folders - 1st is called pages, which is empty and the other is template, where is the file index.php. I want that file to be copy and paste into the folder "pages" and rename it of course. I saw example with ftp.rename() and the result was, i just moved the file from one folder to the other. When i execute that code i get this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: \template\index.php (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

The file exist suck as the folder. What i should change in the code. Thanks !

```
private void generateHTMLPHPfiles() throws IOException{
       String ftpURL="111.111.111.1";
           int port=11;
           String usern="FTP";
           String passw="pass";
           FTPClient ftp=new FTPClient();
           String templ="/template/index.php";
FileInputStream fis1= new FileInputStream(new File(templ));

        try {
           ftp.connect(ftpURL,port);
           ftp.login(usern, passw);
           ftp.enterLocalActiveMode();
           ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Започва качването на файла....");
           boolean changedir=ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/pages");
           boolean donehtml=ftp.storeFile("proba.php", fis1);
//           fis1.close();
           if (donehtml ) {
               System.err.println("Its good!!");
           }

       } catch (IOException ex) {
           System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
       }
       finally{
       try {
           if (ftp.isConnected()) {
               ftp.logout();
               ftp.disconnect();
           }

       }
       catch(IOException ex1){
       ex1.printStackTrace();
       }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Or [How to copy a file on the ftp server to a directory on the same server in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11202215/850848)

Comment: Next time, just google for your question first!