# Copy all files from one FTP directory to another

Tags: python, shell, ftp

I have to copy all existing files inside one ftp directory to another ftp directory on another server. I have not had any experience writing scripts - so any help with this would be great.

I'm wondering if its possible to write this script so that it happens every day at a specific time?

What software/ language should I use for this? Python is a well renowned one, but I want to make sure it suits my requirements.

Can someone give me a basic code implementation for how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [what is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should first find some resources for learning scripting.

Comment: See my answer, though do you really mean *"copy"*? Maybe you actually want to *"move"* the files, don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end you will probably end up downloading the whole directory to a local machine and re-uploading it to the other, as there's generally no way to copy files between directories in FTP.
See [FTP copy a file to another place in same FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3808799/850848).

You will find plenty of examples for downloading and uploading. You do not even need a scripting language. Simply use some command-line FTP client.

For example with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/), you can use the following batch file (`.bat`):

```
winscp.com /log=copy.log /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "get /source/remote/path/* C:\temporary\local\path\" ^
    "put C:\temporary\local\path\* /destination/remote/path/" ^
    "exit"
```

See the guide to [Automating file transfers to and from FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: it's only a dream if other directory user are different ! Probably returned a `Access Denied` message.

Comment: @dsgdfg Sure, but it does not look like the OP wants to copy the files between users. And even if that was required, you just insert another `open` command before the `put`.