# Copying folder from a directory to another on a remote FTP server

Tags: php, ftp

I have a community edition of Alfresco and whenever a new user is created on our database we have to copy a 'default' folder from a directory to the users directory in Alfresco (both the source and destiny directories are in Alfresco server).

I have found many recursive copy functions but none of them worked for me, since they use functions like `opendir()` and `dir()` which aren't available to use on a remote server.

Comment: Soooo... What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really copy a file from one remote directory to another with the FTP protocol.

See [FTP copy a file to another place in same FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3808799/850848).

So you have to download the files and re-upload them to the other directory.

---

Or if you have a shell access to the server, use the `cp` shell command instead or FTP.