# Create replica of file on ftp server

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to create replica of text file and rename it on ftp server. 
I am aware of `copy()` function of `PHP` , but it not working on FTP

HERE IS MY CODE

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
    $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

    if ($login) {

        $fn = 'folderName/f1.txt'; // This is the file whose replica i want to create as a f2.txt
        $newfn = 'folderName/f2.txt';


        if (copy($fn, $newfn)) {
            echo "Done"
        }else{
            echo "Error";
        }
   }
```

Comment: Show us the code you're trying. Is the text file already on the FTP server, or are you uploading it as well?

Comment: Text file is already on server named f.text. What i am trying is the if (copy($fn, $newfn)) {}

Comment: Are you actually using FTP, or are you trying to run a script on your server that will copy the file?

Comment: yeah i am using FTP

Comment: Please show your full code, so we can understand what you are doing.

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: [I don't think that possibility exists in a single command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3808799/ftp-copy-a-file-to-another-place-in-same-ftp)

Comment: @aynber Got it, thanks for sharing.